# Jasmine Testing Subscription To Service Level Observable From OnInit Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on testing a component which has a subscription within the ngOnInit method. Works fine when running in "the wild" but testing fails as there is no subscription object available. I have tried creating a stub svc to build the observable object within my unit test, but can't get it to work.

Here's my Service and Component code (abrv):

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.userSvc.user.subscribe(user => {
    this.currentUser = user; //-- this.userSvc.user (which is an observable on that class) is available in the wild, but not when testing
   })
  }
```

**UserService**

```
  //-- User Subscribe items
  userSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  user = this.userSubject.asObservable(); // this is the property I'm subscribing to which gets set after login.
```

Here is my Test Setup

```
//SvcStub
const usrSvcStub = {
 user : {
  FirstName: "Test",
  LastName: "User",
  Username: "testuser"
 }
}

//Providers Config
 providers: [
    {provide: UserService, useValue: {usrSvcStub}}
   ]
```

When the test fires, I can see through debug that it is loading my "StubSvc" but user is undefined and I cannot subscribe to it. Can someone point me in right direction? Screenie below shows when it loads the component's ngOnInit function and subscribes to the service observable.

[image]

Comment: you are returning an object, you need to return observable on `user`

Comment: did u try my answer

Comment: Yes I did. I had to cast behavior subject to an observable using .asOservable() and all worked. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
const usrSvcStub = {
 user : new BehaviorSubject<any>({
  FirstName: "Test",
  LastName: "User",
  Username: "testuser"
 })
}
```